# SQL query like IN

Tags: mysql

I have one table `oc_product_option_value` where is data:

```
product_id | option_value_id |
------------------------------ 
2262       |     78          |
2262       |     37          |
2263       |     70          | 
2263       |     78          |
2264       |     37          |
2264       |     30          |
```

So, I want to get only just `product_id = 2262`, because it has `option_value_id = 78 and 37`. Another products don't match because they have only just one of this numbers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `HAVING` with `GROUP BY`.

**Query**

```
select `product_id`
from `oc_product_option_value`
where `option_value_id` in (78,37)
group by `product_id`
having count(*) = 2;
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `COUNT` with `DISTINCT` if you have repeating entries with same `option_vale_id` e,g.:

```
SELECT product_id
FROM oc_product_option_value
WHERE option_value_id IN (37, 78)
GROUP BY product_id
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT option_value_id) >= 2;
```